# SQL Selecting & Counting In the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

thanks in advance for any help on this, I am a bit of a newbie to MS SQL and I want to do something that I think is achievable but don't have the know how.

I have a simple table called "suppliers" where I can do (SELECT id, name FROM suppliers ORDER BY id ASC)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ACME |
| 2 | First Stop Business Supplies |
| 3 | All in One Supply Warehouse |
| 4 | Farm First Supplies |

I have another table called "products"

| id | name | supplier_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Item 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Item 3 | 1 |
| 4 | Item 4 | 3 |
| 5 | Item 5 | 2 |

I want to list all the suppliers and get the total amount of products for each supplier if that makes sense on the same row? I am just not sure how to pass the suppliers.id through the query to get the count.

I am hoping to get to this:

| id | name | total_products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACME | 2 |
| 2 | First Stop Business Supplies | 2 |
| 3 | All in One Supply Warehouse | 1 |
| 4 | Farm First Supplies | 0 |

I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three concepts to grasp here. `Left Join`, `group by`, and `Count()`.

```
select s.id, s.name, Count(*) as total_products
from suppliers s
left join products p on s.id=p.supplier_id --the left join gets your no matches
group by s.id, s.name
```

**left join** is a join where all of the values from the first table are kept even if there are no matches in the second.

**Group by** is an aggregation tool where the columns to be aggregated are entered.

**Count()** is simply a count of transactions for the grouped columns.

Comment: Don't use `count(*)` when joining 2 tables, use `count(table2.primary_key)`.

Comment: Not sure about the rationale for not using Count(*). The only time I have ever not done that is when using count(distinct [fieldName])

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I was getting in a right mess trying to figure out joins and counting at the same time, this worked perfectly well when adding in the Count(p.id) instead of the Count(*)

Comment: Just out of interest, it may be something easy, is there a way to omit rows that have zero count? I thought a simple "where Count(p.id) > 0" might do it but I get a "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Comment: 2 different ways. Do not use a left join or add a having count(*)>0... HAVING is the "where" for aggregates. and comes after your group by and before an order by.

Comment: Also, I used a left join instead of an inner join because you had the 0 record in your expected output.

Comment: @Shmiel It's a myth that `count(*)` is bad.  It's fine.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Maybe, you probably know more than me. But there was a few times that I had complete massy results when I used `count(*)` while joining 2 tables, but when I used `count(table2.pk)` or any other column from the second table, it was the right results as expected.

Comment: Count(table2.pk) will not count rows where table2.pk is null, perhaps because of an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
SELECT id, name, C.total_products  
FROM Suppliers S
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT Count(id) AS total_products
   FROM Products P
   WHERE P.supplier_id = S.id
) C
```

Comment: `SELECT SELECT` is that new syntax ?

Comment: Thanks @Luuk my bad, i have updated the answer.